# Adding Style to WYSIWYG Editor in Colormag Theme

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

hello can you tell me how I can add styles to the WYSIWYG editor of your plugin? I’m currently using the Colormag theme. For example, I would like the links to be highlighted and displayed in blue when I hover over them. Thank you.
I have already tried a lot of code but I can't solve the problem
I just tried the following code but nothing happens, maybe a generous person could help me
I have already tried a lot of code but I can't solve the problem
so I created a css file with the modification in css and then the function in the function .php file
[image]

```
a {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

function ajouter_style_editeur() {
    $theme_dir = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
    add_editor_style( $theme_dir . '/custom-editor-style.css' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'ajouter_style_editeur' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Review [documentation for `add_editor_style()` core function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_editor_style/). Will be something like this in `functions.php` of your theme (untested):

```php
add_editor_style( 'path/to/your/editor-style.css' );
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the link I modified my question with my test, but does not work

Comment: There's no code in your question.

Comment: I just put it on

Comment: Please change the properties of `a` to something more obvious (like `color: red`), and provide a screenshot of WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: https://zupimages.net/up/23/23/s3ay.jpg  
thanks for the help

Comment: Will you please upload the image to your question? That way it's on-site and will be available.

Comment: I don't know how to edit my post

Comment: The same way you edited your question to add the code.

Comment: there are too many pending edits on staxk overflow

Comment: Moderator strike; lovely. Are you familiar with using DevTools to inspect element styles?

Comment: no Unfortunately

Comment: here is image added

Comment: Can you please provide screenshot of WYSIWYG in Visual mode? No styling will be applied in Text mode.

Comment: indeed in visual mode the style is well applied but when I look at my article on my style the styles have disappeared
I just uploaded a picture

Comment: Great! For the styles on the frontend you’ll need a separate stylesheet, or a clever combo of editor styles with styles specifically for frontend. Please mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: no nothing works because whatever I change in the secondary css file, the style does not change visually, it stays in red and highlights and when I look at the article on my site no style is applied

Comment: my problem is that the style I put in the custom css file is not taken into account by the editor

Comment: As I mentioned, there are two separate stylesheets: one for your editor, and one for the frontend. This question is specifically about styles in the WYSIWYG editor, which we have solved. If you have another question, then please post another question. Be sure to include the research you've done in your next question.

Comment: I understand your answer better, but whatever I can change my customize css file, no change is made on the editor, it always remains highlighted in red

Comment: If you change your CSS to `color: green`, it doesn’t change?

Comment: thanks for the help
no if I put this nothing changes in the editor
To a {
  color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}

Comment: function wpdocs_add_editor_styles() {
    add_editor_style( 'custom-editor-style.css' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_add_editor_styles' );

Comment: `add_editor_style()` should not be inside an action.